# Auto hide/unhide rows Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a google spreadsheet script.

When the value of a cell changes to a specified value I want it to trigger hide/unhide rows.

Here is my script so far:

```
function autoHide() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
  var cell1 = ("C12");

  if (cell1 == "Others" ) {
    ss.getActiveSheet().showRows(14, 3);
  }

  else if (cell1 == "Additional Discount/s (over and above 25%)" ) {
    ss.getActiveSheet().showRows(17, 4);
  }

  else {
    ss.getActiveSheet().hideRows(14, 7)
  }
}
```

[image: Image of sheet]

Comment: So, what is the problem with your current script?

Comment: hide/unhide rows not working whenever I am changing the cell value

Comment: Are you changing the value in cell `C12`?

Comment: Also, at no point do you use the method `cell.getValue()` to check against your string values.

Comment: I am and changing it manually through a drop down option

Comment: Sorry if I did not make question clearer, to cut it short I want to hide/unhide certain rows if the value in "C12"changes to specific value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear about some points so I assumed you wanted to track the value of cell **C12** when **C12** is edited.

```
function autoHide() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();

  var cellRef = cell.getA1Notation();

  if (cellRef !== "C12") return;
  // This isn't the cell we are looking for, stop executing the function.

  if (value === "Others" ) {

    sheet.showRows(14, 3);

  } else if (value === "Additional Discount/s (over and above 25%)" ) {

    sheet.showRows(17, 4);

  } else {
    sheet.hideRows(14, 7);
  }
}
```

---

If you want to run the function anytime *any* cell is edited, use this code.

Useful if **C12** is a formula and is not updated manually.

```
function autoHide() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var cellRef = "C12";
  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellRef);
  var value = cell.getValue();

  if (value === "Others" ) {

    sheet.showRows(14, 3);

  } else if (value === "Additional Discount/s (over and above 25%)" ) {

    sheet.showRows(17, 4);

  } else {
    sheet.hideRows(14, 7);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'l try these codes and post it here if it works